# My for loop in giving error

Tags: r

I want to save subset of file name summer for different time block ranging from 1 to 10.lm1 will read data of first time block.lm2 for second time block & so on. I have written below for loop but it is not working.Wats the issue?

```
library(openxlsx)
Master=read.xlsx("Master File from Apr-11 to Feb-15.xlsx",sheet="Sheet1")
summer=subset(Master, Season=="Winter")
for (i in 1:10) {
print(i)
lm[i]=subset(summer,Block==i)

}
```

Comment: You might also consider `split(summer, summer$Block)` for this.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to store your data into a list. You can use `lapply` or `sapply` to work over it down the line.

```
out <- vector("list", 10)

for (i in 1:10) {
  message(sprintf("Processing iteration number %s", i))
  out[[i]] <- subset(summer, Block == i)
}
```

Comment: Its is working but I want to save each of my Out[1],Out[2] etc in csv format as out1.csv,out2.csv. What should i do.

Comment: @Engg You can iterate over each element and do whatever you please with it. You can try `sapply` or `lapply`.